# Why thermal expansion different for different lengths of same solid

Tags: thermodynamics

Linear expansion of steel rod of length 10m with 10 kelvin change in temperature  is 1.1×10^-3m but with the  same temperature change 2 meter steel rod expand only upto 0.2×10^-3m. Why is it so?

Comment: Different steels?

Comment: From the definition of coefficient of linear expansion, $\alpha = \frac{1}{L} \dfrac{dL}{dT}$ , I think this is what the OP is asking about @JonCuster

Comment: @HritikNarayan - but in the example given the two bars do not expand in proportion to each other. Perhaps a typo?

Comment: Yeah I think that's the case here.

Answer (score 2):

The expansion per unit length of steel rod will be constant  in both cases. For unit length, let the expansion be = dl. dl is a very small length. It is the change in length of rod of unit length. Therefore new length= 1+dl.
In case of 10m long rod, it can be divided into 10 equal pieces of length 1m each. On heating each piece the new length becomes 1+dl. Now these pieces are rejoined to form a rod of length 10×(1+dl)=10+10×dl. So total change in length =(10+10×dl)m-10m= 10×dl.
In case of 2m long rod the expansion in length=2×dl.
Therefore change in length of longer rod is more than in the smaller rod of same material and same change in temperature.
This can also be understood by the fact that the longer rod has more molecules than in smaller rod. On heating the rods, the intermolecular distance increases by same amount in both rods. But due to more number of molecules the change in intermolecular distance in case of longer rod will add up and produce a greater expansion in overall length of longer rod.

P.S- I think that you have miscalculated the change in length in your question as it should be proportional to their respective lengths

Answer (score 0):

For the same change in temperature, the proportional change in length is the same - when you allow for the rounding of your figures.

The $10m$ rod can be thought of as $5$ smaller rods each $2m$ long. Each of these rods expands by $0.22 \times 10^{-3} m$. (Probably this has been rounded to $0.2\times 10^{-3}m$ because the expansion can only be measured to the nearest $0.1 mm$.) So the total change in length is $1.1 \times 10^{-3} m$, the same as for the $10m$ long rod.